# How to convert Excel sheet into a Vector using Jxl

Tags: java, string, vector, jxl

So I have this variable PV1 who stores from an Excel file the first row. But I want a variable that stores the entire row in a vector.

I use `System.out.println()` just to see if it takes the good column.

```
String PV1;
for(int col = 0;col < columns;col++) 
 {
   for(int row = 1;row < rows;row++) 
    {
      PV1 = sheet.getCell(1, row).getContents();
      System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(PV1)); 
    }  
 }
```

I am using jxl to access the Excel file.

Any help would be much appreciated!

[Edit: This is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NseDB.png) and i need to store in PV1 all the rows.

Comment: Is this vector a `java.util.Vector`? If so, consider using a `java.util.List` instead.

Comment: In my answer I have nested two vectors creating an matrix. In your question is not clear how many dimensions you need.

Comment: I have 43478 rows and 6 columns.

Comment: You should not change radically the question. You should post a new question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you need a vector that should hold all the columns in the first row.

If that is the case, you can do something like this:

```
Vector<Double> firstRow = new Vector<>();
if(rows > 0){
    for(int col = 0;col < columns;col++){
        String pv = sheet.getCell(1, col).getContents();
        firstRow.add(Double.parseDouble(pv)); 
    } 
}
```

You should probably consider using a `List` instead of a `Vector`.

From your comment it seems that you want to retrieve a specific column from all the rows. You can do that like this:

```
int pv1ColumnIndex = 1;
List<Double> pv1Columns = new ArrayList<>();
for(int row = 1;row < rows;row++){// row = 1 to skip the header
    String pv1 = sheet.getCell(pv1ColumnIndex, row).getContents();
    pv1Columns.add(Double.parseDouble(pv1)); 
}
```

Comment: Not really. I need to store in a vector/list all the rows of a column. I uploaded a picture and that can clarify the situation. So in PV1 I want to have all the rows that the column PV1 contains.

Comment: @AntonescuCatalin I've edited my answer. I think the second example will do what you need it to do. I'm not sure what are the parameters to the `getCell()` method. If it is `getCell(rowIndex, columnIndex)` you'll have to replace `pv1ColumnIndex` with `row` and vice versa. Success in continuare.

Answer (score 0):

This will help you

```
    String PV1;
    Object[] data = Object[columns]
    for(int col = 0;col < columns;col++) 
     {
       for(int row = 1;row < rows;row++) 
      {
         PV1 = sheet.getCell(1, row).getContents();
         data[col] = PV1;
         System.out.println(Double.parseDouble(PV1)); 
      }  
     }
```

Comment: Actually `Object[columns]` should be `Object[columns * (rows - 1)]` and why would you use an `Object` array ?

Comment: Yeah you are correct. If you want store data as string then string array is fine. But I can see that you are converting string to a double so I assumed that you are going to convert your data at some point in your code.